# Pandas: Change duplicates respecting multiindex series

Tags: python, pandas, nan, series, multi-index

Take this multi-index series:

```
client_id  y-m    
0          2018-05       13.935563
           2018-06     5326.898967
           2018-07    11968.431680
           2018-08             NaN
           2018-09             NaN
           2018-10    15257.418813
           2018-11             NaN
           2018-12    20509.774900
           2019-01    25187.485960
           2019-02             NaN
           2019-03             NaN
           2019-04             NaN
           2019-05             NaN
           2019-06             NaN
           2019-07             NaN
           2019-08    35943.419296
           2019-09    38253.756910
           2019-10    42289.134021
           2019-11             NaN
           2019-12             NaN
           2020-01             NaN
           2020-02             NaN
           2020-03             NaN
           2020-11             NaN
           2020-12             NaN
           2021-01             NaN
1          2019-07      169.805400
           2019-08      169.805400
           2019-09      169.805400
           2019-10      169.805400
           2019-11      169.805400
           2019-12             NaN
           2020-01             NaN
           2020-07             NaN
           2020-08             NaN
           2021-01             NaN
```

I want to replace the duplicates values considering the first index `client_id` with NaN, maintaining the first value. It is important that the duplicates only by the 1st level index are replaced.

For the example data above, the sequence of repeated values for `client_id == 1` should only keep the value for `2019-07` and the others should be set to NaN as follows:

```
1          2019-07      169.805400
1          2019-08             NaN
1          2019-09             NaN
1          2019-10             NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the duplicated values are consecutive, then you can group by the first index and using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). This will give you a boolean mask that can be used to set the repeated values to NaN.

Code:

```
mask = s.groupby('client_id').shift() == s
s.loc[mask] = np.nan
```

---

If there is no guarantee that the duplicates are consecutive, then you can either first sort the values and apply the above solution:

```
s = s.sort_values()
mask = s.groupby('client_id').shift() == s
s.loc[mask] = np.nan
s = s.sort_index()
```

and then sort by the index to return to the original order.

An alternative solution would be to apply [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to each group:

```
s.loc[s.groupby('client_id').apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep='first'))] = np.nan
```

The result for all solutions will be:

```
client_id  y-m    
0          2018-05       13.935563
           2018-06     5326.898967
           2018-07    11968.431680
           2018-08             NaN
           2018-09             NaN
           2018-10    15257.418813
           2018-11             NaN
           2018-12    20509.774900
           2019-01    25187.485960
           2019-02             NaN
           2019-03             NaN
           2019-04             NaN
           2019-05             NaN
           2019-06             NaN
           2019-07             NaN
           2019-08    35943.419296
           2019-09    38253.756910
           2019-10    42289.134021
           2019-11             NaN
           2019-12             NaN
           2020-01             NaN
           2020-02             NaN
           2020-03             NaN
           2020-11             NaN
           2020-12             NaN
           2021-01             NaN
1          2019-07      169.805400
           2019-08             NaN
           2019-09             NaN
           2019-10             NaN
           2019-11             NaN
           2019-12             NaN
           2020-01             NaN
           2020-07             NaN
           2020-08             NaN
           2021-01             NaN
```

Comment: It solved!. But if the values are duplicated within `client_id`,  but not consecutive, is this going to function as well?

Comment: @DanielArges: No, the original solution assumed that the duplicated values were in order. I added two alternative solutions that will work in the non-consecutive case as well.